# Design an Access Form with Dynamic SQL as Recordsource

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2003

I am pretty new to Access VBA programming. Here is one problem I have when creating a form in Access. I need to link the form's recordsource to a query object which I have already defined. Let's say I have field1, field2, field3, etc. in my query. The end product I would like to present is

1. on top of the form, there are several text boxes for user to input filtering criteria of field1, field2, field3 ... and
2. on a click of a button, a datasheet displays at the bottom of the form with the filtering criteria applied
3. besides the existing fields in my query, I need to include at the end of the datasheet a customized column based on certain calculation result from field1 and field2. Some text could be displayed, for example "Late", "Early" or "On Time"

I have come up with two design approaches, but due to the lack of experience in VBA programming I am not able to accomplish either one of them right now...

**Design 1:**

I have a main form with the criteria input text boxes. This main form is not linked to any data source. Then I have a subform at bottom whose data source is dynamically set by reading the text boxes' values in the main form.

**Design 2:**

I have a single form, but I shift all the criteria boxes to the Form Header section. This form has a record source from my query object. The detail section is used for displaying the data sheet with the form's filter property set to user criteria.

I am not able to do design 1 because I don't know how to set the data source for my sub form dynamically. I am also not able to do design 2 because my form's header section does not appear even I have checked in the design view the form header/footer is enabled.

What can I do to realize my form design? Any alternative design suggestions?

I am using Access 2003 for this development, but I hope my code can be upgradable to Access 2010 in future.

Thanks in advance for your advice.

Comment: for design 1, I would also like to know if the subform should be inserted originally as an unbound object. and later do I need to set the data source of each field in this sub form?

Comment: Have you considered referring to the criteria fields as subform link child fields? Link Master Fields: txtField1, txtField2 -- Link Child Fields: Field1, Field2. The main form does not need to be bound to a recordsource, you can refer to the controls themselves. It may not suit, but if it does, it is by far the best way of filtering a subform.

Comment: @Remou I haven't thought of that way. but when I have the source object of my subform set to a query object and tried to link child fields, I got the error "can't build a link between unbound forms". by setting the source object this way, can I still add extra columns to the sub form? and is the linking relationship one-to-one, like Field1=txtField1, Field2=txtField2... how may I specify a condition like between two field values? thanks

Comment: As I said, it may not suit. You cannot have Like. The subform must be bound to the full data set. It looks like you need to set the subform recordsource dynamically. Do not forget that the name of the subform control (not the form contained) is used when referring to a subform from the main form. This may help http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/Referring_to_a_control_on_a_subform

Comment: You can also set the form content of a subform control dynamically, so if you have not included a form in the subform control, do so, before you try to refer to it.

Comment: @Remou do you mean I need to insert another form inside the subform control? the subform control itself is unbound when it is inserted, am I right? then what do I do to bound it to a query object and at the same time maintain the flexibility of adding more columns?

Comment: I am trying to make sure that we have a distinction between the subform control and the form contained by the subform control. They are two very different things. If your subform control does not contain a form, you cannot refer to the form property. If you wish to build a query and use that as the subform control Source Object, you can, but it is quite a different approach.

Comment: @Remou I got your idea. now I have a subform in my main form and I set the source object of this subform to an existing form object (my_subform) that is originally unbound. then with a button click, I am able to set the recordsource property of my_subform to a query. This works fine so far. but the problem now is I don't see anything displayed in my subform as my_subform is totally empty even it has a record source. how do I go about setting each field of this subform?

Comment: Dynamic fields in a subform are not a good idea. You can set up several fields and set the control source at run time, but it would probably be better to choose a suitable set of fields and use them for your form.

Comment: @Remou thanks! I chose to set the control source instead of the controls themselves dynamically in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With both designs you should build the datasource dynamically, something like this:

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTableOrQuery WHERE 1=1"
If Not IsNull(textBox1) Then
  sql = sql & " And Field1 = '" & textBox1 & "'"
End If
If Not IsNull(textBox2) Then
  sql = sql & " And Field2 = '" & textBox2 & "'"
End If
```

And, finally, assign the sql to the form datasource.

**Design1**

The below code goes in the main form, just next to the above:

```
SubFormControlName.Form.RecordSource = sql
```

**Design2**

To show the controls in the header section you need to set the property DefaultView to *running forms* (I don't know the extact translation, I work with Access in spanish)
In this case, the datasource is assigned to the main form

```
Me.recourdsource = sql
```

For your third point:
You can build calculated field using

```
Iif(fieldA<5,"Early",Iif(fieldA>10,"Late","OnTime"))
```

or you can use [conditional formatting](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/change-the-appearance-of-a-control-by-using-conditional-formatting-HA010208133.aspx). I think this option is most clear

Comment: thanks for your reply. However, I still have problem with the following vba code Me!Child16.Form.RecordSource = sql where Child16 is the name of subform I insert into the main form. I call this with a button click event in my main form. Access gave me error 2467: the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or doesn't exist

Comment: as for design 2, I believe you are referring to the "continuous form" of defaultview property. but I don't like the layout of continuous form here. is there really no way I can do this with datasheet view as defaultview? or is there anywhere else I can place my criteria boxes in a datasheet form?

Comment: Sorry, but for continuous form, there is only that layout. If you prefer a dataset, you should go for option 1.

For the above comment: Make sure that Child16 is the name of the control that contains the subform, not the name of the form. Usually, for avoid this mistakes, I name the form and the control in the same way.

Comment: for the formula you suggest, how do I assign it to my field. currently I have something like `Me!mySubform.Form.myField.ControlSource=Iif(fieldA<5,"Early",Iif(fieldA>10,"Late","OnTime"))` where fieldA is the name of a field in my query object that is the record source of my subform

Comment: It's an approach. But I would prefer to create a new calculated field in your query. In the form, you can treat it as any other field.